# How to uniquely identify the selected value from drop down in Oracle jet which is inside for each bind

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, oracle-jet

1).I have three names Bert,Charles,Denise.

- with their observable Indexes(Used **current.observableIndex**).
- 0: Bert , 1: Charles , 2: Denise
- Their Current Status shown in-front of their names(Used **current.data.status**)

2).Each an every name has drop down and submit button.(Used **oj-bind-for-each**)

3).I can select value from the drop-down and submit(It will catch the selected value from the drop down)

**Action**

- **Initial Page View**

  [image]

Suppose I have selected

- 0: Bert and drop-down value as **Firefox**
- 1: Charles and drop-down value as **Safari**
- 2: Denise and drop-down value as **Opera**
- Then I click the **Submit** button which is from the **0: Bert**

**Problem**

- The Submit Button Catches the **Opera** which I selected last from **2: Denise**

**Expectation**

- I want to get the **Firefox** for the **0: Bert** submit button Click.

How Could I achieve this?

**Code**

dashboard.html

```
      <div>    
      <oj-bind-for-each data="[[dataProvider]]">
          <template>
              <li>
              <oj-bind-text value="[[$current.data.status]]"></oj-bind-text>
              <oj-bind-text value="[[$current.observableIndex]]"></oj-bind-text> : <oj-bind-text value="[[$current.data.name]]"></oj-bind-text>
              <oj-button class='oj-button-sm' on-oj-action= "[[saveData]]">
                  Submit
              </oj-button>
              <oj-select-one id="[[uniquieId]]"
                             on-value-changed="[[selectedValue]]"  options="[[browsers]]" 
                             value="{{$current.data.status}}" style="max-width:20em">
              </oj-select-one>
              </li>

          </template>  
      </oj-bind-for-each>
  </div>
```

dashboard.js

```
define(['accUtils', 'knockout', 'ojs/ojarraydataprovider', 'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojbutton', 'ojs/ojselectcombobox'],
        function (accUtils, ko, ArrayDataProvider) {

            function DashboardViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.uniquieId = ko.observable();

                var users = ko.observableArray([
                    {id: "1", name: "Bert", status: "Internet Explorer"},
                    {id: "2", name: "Charles", status: "Chrome"},
                    {id: "3", name: "Denise", status: "Safari"}
                ]);
                self.dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider(users, {keyAttributes: 'id'});
                self.selectVal = ko.observable('Chrome');
                self.selected = ko.observable();


                self.browsers = ko.observableArray([
                    {value: 'Internet Explorer', label: 'Internet Explorer'},
                    {value: 'Firefox', label: 'Firefox'},
                    {value: 'Chrome', label: 'Chrome'},
                    {value: 'Opera', label: 'Opera'},
                    {value: 'Safari', label: 'Safari'}
                ]);

                self.selectedValue = function (event, current) {

                    var optionValue = event.detail;
                    self.selected(optionValue.value);
                    console.log(self.selected());
                    console.log(optionValue);
                };

                self.saveData = function (event, current) {
                    self.uniquieId(current.observableIndex());
                    console.log(self.uniquieId());
                    console.log(self.selected());
                };

            }

            return DashboardViewModel;
        }
);
```

Comment: Hi @AnuradhaS if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 fixes to be made:

1. In the `oj-select-one` component you are binding the selected value to `"{{$current.data.status}}"`. But for this to work correctly, `$current.data.status` has to be capable of getting its value updated and then reflecting the latest value. This is not possible when you make 'status' a simple string.

Instead, they should be observables:

```
var users = ko.observableArray([
     {id: "1", name: "Bert", status: ko.observable("Internet Explorer")},
     {id: "2", name: "Charles", status: ko.observable("Chrome")}),
     {id: "3", name: "Denise", status: ko.observable("Safari")}
]);
```

In other words, any value bound between the View and Viewmodel that has to be updated through user interaction should be an observable.

2. There is no use of the `selected` observable, because the `selectedValue` function simply updates `selected` to whatever was selected last. Instead, you can use your other variable `uniquieId` to get the correct data because your `saveData` function updates `uniquieId` with the index of the row you just clicked Submit on.

So change your `saveData` function to this:

```
            self.saveData = function (event, current) {
                self.uniquieId(current.observableIndex());
                console.log(self.uniquieId());
                console.log(users()[self.uniquieId()].status());
            };
```

Comment: I'm grateful for your answer and it solved the problem.

Comment: I am happy it helped.. :)